# Multiple Backgroundworkers with HttpListeners in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a simple server program, where I want to instantiate many "listeners" at the same time, so my requests are not processed sequentially but in parallel. I thought I could make a number of `BackgroundWorker()` instances, which would create an `HttpListener()` , like this (in my main function):

```
private static List<BackgroundWorker> _backgroundWorkers = new List<BackgroundWorker>();
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var numW = 5;
        foreach (var w in Enumerable.Range(0, numW))
        {
            _backgroundWorkers.Add(new BackgroundWorker());
            _backgroundWorkers[w].DoWork += _backgroundWorkers_DoWork;
            _backgroundWorkers[w].RunWorkerCompleted += _backgroundWorkers_RunWorkerCompleted;

            //start worker's server
            lock(_backgroundWorkers[w])
                _backgroundWorkers[w].RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```

And the `_backgroundWorkers_DoWork` function just calls the following function:

```
public static void StartServer()
{
    var httpListener = new HttpListener();
    var server = new Server(httpListener, _url, ProcessResponse);
    server.Start();
}
```

But my main program just ends right away. Any tips ?

Comment: Just add `Console.ReadLine();` in the end of `Main`. Btw why do you use `lock`?

Comment: A listener automatically listens for connections from more than one client so you cannot  have multiple listeners using same port number.